# jquery mobile: get selected radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm not sure how can I get the selected radio button in jQuery mobile (I'm using version 1.4.3). The checked attribute doesn't change whenever I click one of the radio buttons. Actually, when I inspect the elements I see that only attribute data-cacheval is changing. Is it safe to use this attribute to get the selected radio button? This is the code I'm using for the radio buttons:

```
                    <input type="radio" name="chkViewType" id="chkViewType2"  data-mini="true">
                    <label for="chkViewType2" data-mini="true">List</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="chkViewType" id="chkViewType1" data-mini="true">
                    <label for="chkViewType1" data-mini="true">Map</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

e.g.

```
$("[name='chkViewType']:checked")
```

Also, you should probably read the **Attributes vs. Properties** paragraph in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).